# First order By Substitution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

1. Given that 
   $$y= c_1x^2 + c_2x^4 + 3$$ is a two-parameter family of solutions of 
   $$(x^2)y'' - (5x)y' + 8y = 24$$ on an infinite interval, determine whether a member of the family can be found that satisfies the conditions

$$y(-1)=0, y(1)=4 \\
y(0)=1 , y(1)= 2 \\
y(0)=3 , y(1)=0 \\
y(1)=3 , y(2)=15 $$

Comment: Not all of them presumably... each of the four?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a hint (I assumed that each of these was a distinct pair to test) and you should do the rest.

$$y (x) = c_1x^2 + c_2x^4 + 3$$

We are given the IC: $y(-1)=0, y(1)=4$

Substituting, we get two equations and two unknowns (which may or may not provide a solution):

$y (-1) = c_1 + c_2 + 3 = 0$

$y (1)~~~ = c_1 + c_2 + 3 = 4$

Does a solution exist in this case? No.

Comment: @amWhy: Actually both of you guys are great - you are very helpful and take an active role in making MSE a better place and I really enjoy reading your responses.

Comment: Thanks, that's very kind of you. I think you are a warm and welcoming contributor yourself!

Comment: Ugh...I'm having a "slow" night (7:41 pm my time)... :-/

Comment: @amWhy: I am PT - so two hours earlier - just got home from work. Are the kids on break? The frequency of postings seems to have changed. I also get what you mean!

Comment: Yes, I've wondered about that: I think spring break is often the week before, or the week after, Easter...so that may account for some of it. I just like to go to bed with a few upvotes...or the chance to help out OP's...

Comment: Me too- I wrote my top-reasons why I might be an MSE addict and that is one of them! :-)

Comment: I hear you! I put a few in your pocket ;-)  I think I should look for a MSE Anonymous support group for addicts ;-)